# Wildcard instead of domain in DKIM signature

Tags: linux, email, dns, postfix-mta, dkim

I'm trying to setup OpenDKIM on my server.

I'm using Virtualmin, I have something like 30 domains on my server.
After setting up DKIM from VirtualMin messages are being signed, but instead of domain there is a wildcard (*) in `d` parameter, so it fails to be verified. In opendkim.conf I set `SigningTable refile:/etc/dkim-signingtable` so it should process wildcards.
Based on signature, verifiers are trying to make a DNS query for `default._domainkey.*` and it fails.

How can I force to replace `d=*` to `d=example.com` in DKIM signature? What am I missing?

**UPD**: this is in my SigningTable: `*  default`